# portion of powershell variable value to display

Tags: powershell

I have a variable whose value is "Big Apple" and that is what I am displaying on my form. I want to keep the variable value as it is  but like to display just "Apple" from it.
I do not want to use `SubString`. Just through loop somehow or any other way. Is it possible? How to do it?

```
$result.content = "Big Apple"
foreach($number in $result.content)
{
    $result.content "Apple"  //for display
}
```

Comment: `Split()`?  If you know the format of the content (e.g. always two strings) and which part you want (e.g. second string), then you could do something like this:  `$result.content.split()[1]`

Comment: @boxdog Thanks it works.

Comment: I posted my suggestion as an answer.  Feel free to accept it :-)

Answer (score 1):

If you know the format of the content (e.g. always two strings) and which part you want (e.g. second string), then you could do something like this:

`$result.content.split()[1]`

If you are not sure how many parts there are in the string, but always want the last one, do this:

`$result.content.split()[-1]`